# Additional Long press option (Android) while messaging / typing text

Tags: android

Long press options (Android) while messaging / typing text, in addition to Paste and Clipboard options, I want to have another option when touched pastes specific text(s). How can I do this? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onLongClickListener

For example:

```
youEditText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //What happens when you long click
        }
    });
```

Hope this helped!